# Fail to `(require "COCOA")` with Mac ports Clozure Common Lisp

Tags: cocoa, common-lisp, ccl

I have installed the package ccl with Mac ports. Now I want to use the Cocoa bridge.

```
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.8  (DarwinX8664)!
? (require "COCOA")
> Error: Permission denied : #P"/opt/local/share/ccl/1.8/temp bundle64.app/Contents/252752233492590994.tem"
> While executing: %CREATE-FILE, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
```

If I start `ccl64` with `sudo` it works all right. But I would like to be able to do this as a normal user. How should I do it?

Comment: On mac you've to manually install CCL as @Clayton Stanley show below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a Mac, the easiest way to run Clozure CL is to load it from Apple's Mac App Store.

https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/clozure-cl/id489900618?mt=12

That way it gets installed in the Applications folder and running the Cocoa-App is no problem, since it is provided. But then you would run the Cocoa-based IDE version of CCL.

If you install CCL from MacPorts, I guess that the App is not existing. You would need to have the rights for the directory to create the necessary files.

Otherwise I would just install a fresh CCL from Clozure's repository:

http://ccl.clozure.com/download.html

Comment: This version opens a REPL in a new window and thus does not work well with SLIME. Is there a way to make this work nicely with Emacs’ SLIME?

Comment: I believe there's an option under General in the app preferences to start a swank listener.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn co http://svn.clozure.com/publicsvn/openmcl/release/1.8/darwinx86/ccl
```

while in `~` is probably the most straightfoward way to achieve what you want.

If you'd like to work with MacPorts to manage ccl (instead of the svn method above), then run

```
sudo chown -R $USER /opt/local/share/ccl
```

Note that the latter case does make me a bit uncomfortable, because if you try to `sudo port uninstall ccl`, MacPorts does not completely remove the share/ccl directory, presumably because the `(require :cocoa)` call adds compiled binaries to that directory that Macports is not tracking.

To get the MacAppStore version to work, you'd probably need to find the ccl binary buried inside the ccl.app directory, and launch that for slime. Might not be a bad way to go either.

Note that any way you do this, once you `(require :cocoa)`, you'll have a separate cocoa listener pop up while slime is running. I just move it off to the side once it opens. If you find a way to suppress this listener window after `(require :cocoa)`, I'd be interested to know that.

But I'd recommend the first (svn) method. That's the one I use with slimv, and it's the one that Clozure recommends on their downloads page.